# Rails undefined method 'groups' for rails module

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Working on Mac OS X, trying to learn rails.  When I type: "rails generate Scaffold User name:string email:string", I get the following error:

```
    /Users/dnf1991/rails_projects/demo_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `groups' for Rails:Module (NoMethodError)
from /Users/dnf1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:15:in `require'
from /Users/dnf1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try `scaffold` in lower-case. (I get a different error when I use `Scaffold` in upper-case, also 1.9.2-p290 w/ Rails 3.0.9).

Comment: No luck with that unfortunately

Comment: What do you get when you do a `bundle list`?

Comment: Gems included by the bundle:
  * abstract (1.0.0)
  * actionmailer (3.0.9)
  * actionpack (3.0.9)
  * activemodel (3.0.9)
  * activerecord (3.0.9)
  * activeresource (3.0.9)
  * activesupport (3.0.9)
  * arel (2.0.10)
  * builder (2.1.2)
  * bundler (1.0.18)
  * erubis (2.6.6)
  * i18n (0.5.0)
  * mail (2.2.19)
  * mime-types (1.16)
  * polyglot (0.3.2)
  * rack (1.2.3)
  * rack-mount (0.6.14)
  * rack-test (0.5.7)
  * rails (3.0.9)
  * railties (3.0.9)
  * rake (0.9.2)
  * rdoc (3.9.4)
  * sqlite3 (1.3.3)
  * thor (0.14.6)
  * treetop (1.4.10)
  * tzinfo (0.3.29)

Comment: Did you by any chance generate the rails app on rails 3.1 then changed the rails version to 3.0.x, and bundle update?  I had the same message after having done this.

Comment: Hmm let me check. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Mike K, this was the problem for me.  I created a new gemset in rvm, switched to it, ran `bundle install`, problem solved.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem following the same guide you are.  I deleted the project and re-generated, and **did not** follow the instructions to modify gemfile in the project to use 1.3.3 version of sql (and didn't comment out the other default inclusions) and the error went away.