# "undefined method 'groups' for Rails:Module" when running "rails generate rspec:install" on Mac

Tags: ruby

```
$ rails generate rspec:install

/Users/AlbertoRDZ/Desktop/rails_projects/sample_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `groups' for Rails:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/AlbertoRDZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:15:in `require'
    from /Users/AlbertoRDZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Questions dealing with the same symptom: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822904/undefined-method-groups-for-railsmodule and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463642/rails-undefined-method-groups-for-rails-module. Not sure whether to close because I can't tell whether the answers are applicable, but they might be of help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it works with the following:

In `config/application.rb` substitute

```
if defined?(Bundler)
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
end
```

with

```
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)
```