# Rails server command not functioning ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have installed rvm ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.0.5, and am trying right now to enter the "rails server" command line but this is what I get:

```
badr@Badoo:~/rails_projects/first_app$ rails s
/home/badr/rails_projects/first_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `groups' for Rails:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I have been following [this tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning#sec-rails_server) . I'm using ubuntu 12.04 lts and I guess I don't need to tell you that I'm a newbie...

I really don't know what's wrong (railties gem? the rvm?), I've been googling for a solution the whole day.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a reason you are using such an old stack? Try using ruby 2.0 and rails4 or at least 3.2. I don't know exactly what's wrong here but I guess it somehow could be a problem between your ruby version and your rails version.

Comment: Possible duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822904/undefined-method-groups-for-railsmodule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First. update your rails to the current stable version 3.2.13 and see if the error is gone (It will be) also update your ruby to 2

---

else:

See if this works:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13275655/1379394

In `config/application.rb` substitute

```
if defined?(Bundler)
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
end
```

With

```
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)
```

And another question. why are you using rails 3.0.5?
3.2.13 released Mar 18, 2013

Comment: Oh thank you so much! :)  I installed rails 3.0.5 so that I could follow that tutorial. But I didn't think about that, so I reinstalled everything with the last updates and everyhting works fine now. I guess I need to follow a more recent tutorial/book. thanks again :)

Comment: Yes you need to search for tutorials on rails 3.2 or higher. Then you know it will always work. great I could help.